# What kind of connector is this? Looking for an adapter

Tags: hard-disk, adapter

It doesn't look like IDE, nor does it look like SATA to me. It is FEMALE, but doesn't look like pins would fit into it.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the data, and don't know what kind of adapter to buy.

(photo of Connector to an HD from an old -- circa 1989 -- Compaq Presario 2100)
[image]

Comment: It would help to make a picture with the focus on the pins

Comment: Consider to examine the portion of the connection shown in the image for the ability to be removed. It's not out of the question that you can pry it free (evenly) to present a conventional IDE connection array.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like this:

Laptop Hard Drive Connector IDE 44 Adapter voor (for) Dell

[Adapter](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32808574696.html?_randl_currency=EUR&_randl_shipto=NL&src=google&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=494-037-6276&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=6459980570&albag=76980386066&trgt=294505072980&crea=nl32808574696&netw=u&device=c&albpg=294505072980&albpd=nl32808574696&gclid=Cj0KCQjwkOqZBhDNARIsAACsbfK6CI2e7zbS02uuTJeGsPD7j6yOMhvGQTrpXjgFGurHd9t0S0cfznoaAlT_EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&aff_fcid=476914c6bf804444ac8ec5881d415092-1664828556094-09315-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=476914c6bf804444ac8ec5881d415092-1664828556094-09315-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=bd92efd4cb0b400ab2ae9f0614146113&afSmartRedirect=y)

This question may also help:

https://superuser.com/questions/1705665/why-are-the-44-pin-connector-in-laptop-ide-pata-drives-male-while-the-connecto

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling this is the correct answer; I will mark it as such as soon as the prescribed adapter has arrived and it works. Should be here by Oct 14th. Thank you!